# windows forms security c#

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, security-roles

I am developing a Windows Forms application in C#. I have created user authentication within this application, and I have to restrict access to different functionalities to users depending on their permissions.

Is there a framework that can help me with that?

Comment: Do you have an active directory?

Comment: Could you provide more details on how you implemented user authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many options:

[Unify Windows Forms and ASP.NET Providers for Credentials Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163807.aspx)

Possibly the simplest solution is to use Windows role authentication along with database schema to represent what access roles have. The precise implementation depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application going to run in a Microsoft Domain? (Will your users log into a domain using active directory?)

If so then you can employ the .Net Frameworks System.Security namespace to manage access quite easily.

Here is a [Channel 9 overview of System.Security](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/trobbins/Looking-at-the-SystemSecurityAccessControl-Namespace) and the [MSDN Overview of System.Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.aspx).

If you are not on a domain, it is generally not too difficult to validate what ever credentials are available and marshal them into a custom IIdentity & IPrinicipal object that will meet your needs.